# What is an active character's character code in the "eyes" of an \if construct?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

According to the TeXbook's* description of the

```
\if<token1><token2>
```

construct on p. 209 (the emphasis is mine)

> `TeX` will expand macros following `\if` until two unexpandable tokens are found. If either token is a control sequence, `TeX` considers it to have character code 256 and category code 16, unless the current equivalent of that control sequence has been `\let` equal to a non-active character token. In this way, **each token specifies a `(character code, category code)` pair**.

What if one, or both, of the unexpandable tokens is an active character, e.g.

```
\catcode`@=13%
\if\noexpand @ ...
```

What is an active character's effective character code in the "eyes" of an `\if` construct?

---

* 20th printing, Addison-Wesley 1991

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you suppress expansion with `\noexpand` then it acts like a command name so is a character code if it is let to a character,

If you suppress expansion with `\string` then `\if` sees a non-active token of catcode 12, with the character code of the original character.

```
\catcode`@=13
\let@=X

\if\noexpand @X yes \else no\fi


\if\noexpand @ \string@ yes \else no\fi


\bye
```

makes

yes no

as `\noexpand` tests equal to X here as it is `\let` to X note however that if the character is `\let` to a character as here, then it isn't expandable so the `\noexpand` isn't needed.

Comment: What if the active character isn't `\let` to anything?

Comment: @EvanAad it acts like a csname all non-character control sequences are equal to each other but not equal to any character

Comment: Then why does the following manuscript outputs 'no'? `\catcode\`@=13\if @\relax yes\else no\fi\bye`

Comment: @EvanAad you expanded the if before assigning the catcode

Comment: Why isn't the textual order maintained?

Comment: put a space after the 13, it is expanding `\if` while trying to finish the number to assign the catcode  `\count0=13\ifx ab 2\else 4\fi` assigns count0 to be 134

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful! Your code is

```
\catcode`@=13%
\if\noexpand @ ...
```

The first line starts with `\catcode`, so TeX starts making an assignment. It finds the number  `` `@ `` (an alphabetical constant), so the assignment is to the category  code of `@`. Then `=` is basically ignored, because it's optional and now TeX wants to see a `<number>`.

It finds two digits, but the evaluation of the `<number>` only ends when a non-digit comes along, with macro expansion.

If you remove the `%`, the endline generates a space token and this is a non-digit, so the `<number>` TeX is looking for is determined to be `13` (and the space token will be ignored).

With the `%`, TeX finds `\if`, which is expandable, so TeX expands it. The expansion of `\if` is null, but first TeX expands tokens until finding two unexpandable ones and compares them; after the comparison it will return true or false.

The next token is `\noexpand`, which is itself expandable, so it's expanded; its expansion is null, but the next token, whatever it is, is temporarily made equivalent to `\relax`, if an expandable control sequence or the character itself if an active character, and this ends the lookup for the first unexpandable token.

The next token is `@` which *has not* changed its category code yet, because the assignment is not over. Only after finding the next unexpandable token, in this case a space, TeX determines that the `<number>` it was still looking for is indeed `13` and will proceed to perform the assignment.

Check the following code, where groups are used to bound the change in category code so not to spoil the following tests.

```
\let\at=@

\begingroup
\catcode`@=13%
\if\noexpand @\at \message{true}\else\message{false}\fi
\endgroup

\begingroup
\catcode`@=13%
\if @\at \message{true}\else\message{false}\fi
\endgroup

\begingroup
\catcode`@=13
\if @\at \message{true}\else\message{false}\fi
\endgroup
```

The output on the terminal is

```
true true
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \if @
          \relax \message{true}\else\message{false}\fi
```

and only in the third test `@` has become active before the `\if` test is performed.

If the third test is

```
\catcode`@=13
\if \noexpand @\at \message{true}\else\message{false}\fi
```

then it will return true as well, because `\noexpand @` will just return the character `@` with no ability to expand.

Moral of the story: *always leave a space after a constant*.